# How to save a csv file to a certain folder on computer?

Tags: python, csv

I don't understand the **dest_url=r'goog.csv'** part of the program. I think it is used to save the file we get from the Internet to the computer, but how does the computer understand that it has to save the file, when there is no save function to sth like that. It is as if we just have a dest_url variable and assign it a string value.

```
from urllib import request

goog_url = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&d=8&e=2&f=2014&g=d&a=2&b=27&c=2014&ignore=.csv'


def download_stock_data(csv_url):
    response = request.urlopen(csv_url)
    csv = response.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r'goog.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()

download_stock_data(goog_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the very next line *opens* the file for writing.

```
fx = open(dest_url, "w")
```

The `"w"` signifies **write** mode.
The next 2 lines use this `fx` object to write to the file using a **stream**.

In the end `fx.close()` flushes the buffer (i.e. write whatever is left to the file) and then closes the stream and the file is saved.

Comment: I still feel confused, though. Isn't the first parameter in the "open" function the name of the file? How does the computer know if we have actually saved the file?

Comment: Indeed, the first argument is the name of the file. `dest_url` has the name of the file, doesn't it?

Comment: The problem is that the guy in the tutorial says that we save whatever we downloaded from the Internet to a file called goog.csv.  Is this a correct statement?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it. The code sends a request, reads the response line by line and writes it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This was very confusing to me at first. When the script is run, the file name is saved in the same Python folder as the script, so Bucky simply took the file name and passed it to a variable (dest_url). Because the file name resides in the same script folder, the computer automatically knows "Goog.csv".

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with data frames or any other file types , pandas library could be your best bet

import pandas as pan

so in this case if we have a dataframe...

file = pan.DataFrame(" path of the dataframe or content of dataframe")
file.to_csv(" example.csv or path to save csv")

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation:

```
dest_url = r'goog.csv'    # this line will only hold the name of future file, dont think like this variable will create a file"
fx = open(dest_url, "w")  # Here open() method will bring you a blank csv file with file name as det_url in which we have already assigned some value to it. and 'w' will allow the file to be writable. 

for line in lines:        # In order to load goog.csv file with the date we have already captured in lines variable, we need to user for loop, as this is a easy way to feed the empty file of any type.
    fx.write(line + "\n") # Here write() will fetch each of the strings present inside lines variable and writes on goog.csv file as you already know. once the for loop exits, it will save automatically the contents present inside it.
    fx.close()            # This is exit the file after saving the changes.
```